# Every smooth fiber bundle admits an Ehresmann connection?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, fibration

Is it true that every locally trivial fibration(fiber bundle) in smooth category admits an Ehresmann connection? The converse is obviously true, and it's one of the conclusion of the Ehresmann's theorem.

Suppose $(U_\alpha \subset M, \Phi_\alpha : \pi^{-1}(U_\alpha) \to U_\alpha \times F)$ be a trivialization of the fiber bundle $(E, \pi, M)$. Then, for each $U_\alpha$, we could give a natural connection(splitting) of $\mathrm{T} E|U_\alpha$ by
$$
\mathrm{H} E|U_\alpha:= \{ \partial_t|_{t=0}\Phi^{-1}_\alpha(\gamma(t),x) \mid x \in M \}
$$
However, there always be a gluing problem. Since transition map doesn't preserve the horizontal splitting, we couldn't construct the Ehresmann connection in this way.

So, here is the question. Are there a canonical way to construct an Ehresmann connection from smooth fibration? If we are dealing with vector bundle, then we could canonically gives a metric, and we could choose a compatible connection structure. So, it's done. However, if the fiber is an arbitrary manifold $F$, then what would be happen? Are there exists an obstruction?

Comment: Given a surjective submersion $\pi\colon E\to B$, you have the vertical subbundle $VE:=\ker T\pi\subset TE$. Now, if you pick a Riemannian metric $g$ on $E$, then $H:=(VE)^\perp$, the orthogonal complement of VE wrt $g$, should give you an Ehresmann connection on $E$, no?

Comment: @agt Ah, that makes sense. I had an idea to use a metric or some nondegenerate differential form on $E$, but I forgot the usual construction of the splitting. Most of them uses such construction. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Glad to have been helpful. If that solves your doubt, I can post as an full answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a surjective submersion $\pi\colon E\to B$, you have the vertical subbundle $VE:=\ker T\pi\subset TE$. Now, if you pick a Riemannian metric $g$ on $E$, then $H:=(VE)^\perp$, the orthogonal complement of $VE$ with respect to $g$, will give you an Ehresmann connection on $E$